# Ben is at risk of receiving a “not satisfactory” for/in Maths

Tags: grammar, prepositions

> I am writing to inform you that Ben is at risk of receiving a “not satisfactory” **for/in** Maths.

Context: An email to notify the parents that their child is at risk of failing the unit.

Should "for" or "in" be used in the above sentence? Thank you.

Comment: You could use either.  You can get marks for/in a subect.